# Authenticating WCF DataServices

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am trying to authenticate calls to a WCF DataServices service via Silverlight.  Essentially, when a user logs in they get a special hash which should be embedded in the headers of every request to the WCF DataServices.  Currently use this as a check via a QueryInterceptor method eg

```
    [QueryInterceptor("Orders")]
    public Expression<Func<Orders,bool>> OnQueryOrders()
    {
        string hash = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("MyHeader");

        if(!TestHash(hash))
        {
            return o => false;
        }
        else
        {
            return o => true;
        }
    }
```

This seems like the WORST way to achieve this.  Is there any hook in WCF Dataservices the runs before a query is run that you can use to cancel a request?  Bear in mind this service is stateless and has no access to session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think I resolved this issue myself.  By overriding the OnStartProcessingRequest I can throw an exception if it doesn't suit e.g.

```
    protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("MyMagicHeader")))
        {
            throw new DataServiceException(404, "Access denied!");
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: YOu should return a 403 (Forbidden) instead of a 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Awesome! Why can't we do this for authentication instead of stupid basic cust auth. This is way more safer right? I can encrypt a message or token and have it validated on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered WCF Message Inspectors? I think (not guaranteed) the message inspector will be hit before the query interceptor so and you can inspect the headers and verify the users hashed value. Here's a good link with info on [Writing Message Inspectors](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx)